# How can I trigger a change event manually?

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfidle

http://jsfiddle.net/33uosw6c/1/

I have a combobox as shown

```
<select id="BrandNames">
<option value="3001">KFC</option>
</select>


$(document).on('change', 'select#BrandNames', function(event) {

    alert('hii');

});
```

How can I trigger a chnage event manually ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('select#BrandNames').trigger('change');
```

or

```
var event    = jQuery.Event('change');
event.target = $(document).find('select#BrandNames').get(0);
$(document).trigger(event);
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/33uosw6c/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

**try this** - Use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#BrandNames").trigger('change');
});
```